# How to disable password

Tags: raspbian, retropie, update, security, login

I was getting ready to upgrade from a raspberry pi 3b+ to a pi 4 for retro pi gaming. I updated my SD card to prepare it for the new board, but I got a little "surprise".
After the card was updated it started asking me for a password to activate the pi. I know how important security is, but this is only a gaming machine. I find it very annoying to have to plug in a keyboard every time I want to play my games. Is there a way to turn off the password login? If this makes any difference retropie runs off of Raspbian lite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `sudo raspi-config`
2. Option 3 "Boot Options"
3. Option 1 "Desktop / CLI"
4. Option 2 "Console Autologin" press right key to highlight and hit "OK"
5. `sudo reboot`